# Como hacer el success de un plugin propio de javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

intento hacer un plugin propio de autocomplete sin utilizar ninguna libreria mas que jquery y bootstrap. Bueno mi pregunta es la siguiente.

Quisiera retornar el valor cuando realize click en el despegable del autocomplete para luego la data q me devuelva poder manipularla algo asi como el ajax.

Un ejemplo:

```
$(miInputId).ItsaAutocomplete({<br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;source:myArray<br>
})<br>
.success(function(response){<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(response)<br>
});
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda, gracias

Comment: eso lo harias en el success, checa esto: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Comment: hmm ya e visto ese enlace pero no me ayuda el código que tengo es el de abajo. Haber si lo puedes checkear.

Comment: tambien tienes el de la documentacion oficial de jquery: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: como te fijaras es al escribir , pero en tu caso debes invocar en el evento onclick llamar  tu funcion para traer los valores y mostrarlos

Answer (score 0):

hmm no necesariamente mi codigo es el siguiente y es exactamente en el success donde quiero recibir el valor pero cuando quiero mostrarlo en un console.log no me bota nada.

```html
(function($){
 var oldget = $.fn.get;
 $.fn.extend({
     autocomplete  : function (options = new Array()) {
      let caja_id = 'autocomplete-'+this[0].id;
      var that = this;
      this.__create(that,caja_id)
      this.__hover(that,caja_id)
      this.__click(that,caja_id)
      this.__keys(that,options,caja_id)
   return this
     },
     __create   : function(that,caja_id){
      $(that).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
      var myTextBox    = $(that);
      var element_width   = $(that).width() + 18;
      var element_height   = $(that).height() + 10;
      var element_coordenadas = $(that).offset();
   $('body').append('<div class="autocomplete-panel" id="'+caja_id+'"><ul class="list-group"></ul></div>');
       
   $('#'+caja_id).width(element_width);
   $('#'+caja_id).offset({top:element_coordenadas.top + element_height,left:element_coordenadas.left});
     },
     __keys    : function(that,options,caja_id){
      $(that).keyup(function(event) {
    $('#'+caja_id+' .list-group').empty();
    var myText   = $(that).val();
    var mySearch  = '';
    var n = 1;
    $.each(options.source, function(index, val) {  
     mySearch  = val;
     let myReg  = new RegExp(myText.toUpperCase() + '(\n.*)*');
     let myMatch = (mySearch.toUpperCase()).match(myReg);
     if (myMatch){
      var res = (mySearch).toUpperCase().replace(myText.toUpperCase(), "<strong>"+myText.toUpperCase()+"</strong>");
      $('#'+caja_id+' .list-group').append('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-'+n+(n==1 ? ' active' : '')+'" data-position="'+n+'" data-catacter="'+mySearch+'">'+res+'</li>');
      n++;
     }
    });
   });
     },
     __hover   : function(that,caja_id){
      $(document).on('mouseover', '#'+caja_id+' .list-group .list-group-item', function(event) {
          var position = $(this).data('position');
    $('#'+caja_id+' .list-group .list-group-item').removeClass( "active" );
    $('#'+caja_id+' .list-group .list-group-item-'+position).addClass( "active" );
   });
     },
     __click   : function(that,caja_id){
      $(document).on('click', '#'+caja_id+' .list-group .list-group-item', function(event) {
    var datos = [];
    $.each($(this).data(), function(index, val) {
     datos.push(val);
     $(that).val(datos[1]);
    });
          $('#'+caja_id+' .list-group').empty();
          that.success(that,datos);
   });
     },
     success   : function(that,datos){
      var ret = oldget.apply(that, arguments);
      return ret;
     }
 });
})(jQuery);

 var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
 $('#txtautocomplete').autocomplete({
  source:availableTags,
 }).success(function(response){
  console.log(response);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Autocompletado utilizando **boostrap**, **jquery** y **jquery-ui**.

> Esta no es una solución propia. La referencia [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285813/style-jquery-autocomplete-in-a-bootstrap-input-field).

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.ui-autocomplete > li > div {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-active,
.ui-state-focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="container">
  <h1>jQuery UI Autocomplete with Bootstrap Styling</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tags">Tags</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```